# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView cannot be cast to com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, kotlin, android-mapview

Hi I'm working with here SDK for android and I keep getting this error 
my project has a navigation drawer and I'm trying to have a map in one of its fragments with here SDK 
here are my XML and Kotlin code and the error
my error :

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView cannot be cast to com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment
        at com.example.pplin_mobilite.ui.Passager.PassagerFragment.onActivityCreated(PassagerFragment.kt:22)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2717)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6758)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)`

my kotlin class :

```
class PassagerFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    // Search for the Map Fragment
    val mapFragment = map_frag as AndroidXMapFragment
    // initialize the Map Fragment and
    // retrieve the map that is associated to the fragment
    mapFragment.init { error ->
        if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
            // now the map is ready to be used
            mapFragment.map
            // ...
        } else {
            println("ERROR: Cannot initialize AndroidXMapFragment")
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications,container,false)
}
```

}

and my xml :

```
 <fragment
    class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

    />
```

Comment: did you double check to make sure `map_frag` references the correct XML layout shown above?

Comment: yes even changed it right now and it's still the same, I used MapView in my xml at first and got this error but then I changed it to fragment and I still have the same error...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the fragment from **Here documentation**, as it looks like you are, and putting it inside another fragment, you should use:

```
val mapfragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment) as AndroidXMapFragment
```

Then you find the fragment and not the View (since it is not a view), because, if you inspect `mapfragment`, it already extends Fragment()

Answer (score 0):

Try using the supportFragmentManager:

```
val mapfragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_frag) as AndroidXMapFragment?
```